# R: Replacing rownames of data frame by a substring[2]

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, galaxy

I have a question about the use of gsub. The rownames of my data, have the same partial names. See below:

```
> rownames(test)
[1] "U2OS.EV.2.7.9"   "U2OS.PIM.2.7.9"  "U2OS.WDR.2.7.9"  "U2OS.MYC.2.7.9"
[5] "U2OS.OBX.2.7.9"  "U2OS.EV.18.6.9"  "U2O2.PIM.18.6.9" "U2OS.WDR.18.6.9"
[9] "U2OS.MYC.18.6.9" "U2OS.OBX.18.6.9" "X1.U2OS...OBX"   "X2.U2OS...MYC"
[13] "X3.U2OS...WDR82" "X4.U2OS...PIM"   "X5.U2OS...EV"    "exp1.U2OS.EV"
[17] "exp1.U2OS.MYC"   "EXP1.U20S..PIM1" "EXP1.U2OS.WDR82" "EXP1.U20S.OBX"
[21] "EXP2.U2OS.EV"    "EXP2.U2OS.MYC"   "EXP2.U2OS.PIM1"  "EXP2.U2OS.WDR82"
[25] "EXP2.U2OS.OBX"
```

In my previous question, I asked if there is a way to get the same names for the same partial names. See this question: [Replacing rownames of data frame by a sub-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191429/replacing-rownames-of-data-frame-by-a-sub-string)

The answer is a very nice solution. The function gsub is used in this way:

```
 transfecties = gsub(".*(MYC|EV|PIM|WDR|OBX).*", "\\1", rownames(test)
```

Now, I have another problem, the program I run with R ([Galaxy](http://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/)) doesn't recognize the | characters. My question is, is there another way to get to the same solution without using this |?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.  What program do you run with R?  What errors do you get?

Comment: I run R in galaxy (http://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/) and I need to fill in the variable in this way: MYC|EV|PIM|WDR|OBX But galaxy doesn't recognize it

Comment: Have you tried escaping or double escaping the `|` signs?

Comment: Why don't you ask the Galaxy guys why this won't work in their application? The code is valid R.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you may have to write a function that uses a loop or if statements combined with `grep` to test for each phrase separately.  But I am not going to do your work for you.

Comment: Just to back up the comment from Gavin Simpson, I have tried it and it works fine in plain R (i.e. no galaxy). However, there is a trailing bracket missing in your code - could that be the answer?

Comment: @Lisann : please use `c()` or dput to give us an example to work with. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Joris Meys, Sorry for not giving an example to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the "|" character, you can try something like :

```
Rnames <-
c( "U2OS.EV.2.7.9",   "U2OS.PIM.2.7.9",  "U2OS.WDR.2.7.9",  "U2OS.MYC.2.7.9" ,
 "U2OS.OBX.2.7.9" , "U2OS.EV.18.6.9"  ,"U2O2.PIM.18.6.9" ,"U2OS.WDR.18.6.9"  )

Rlevels <- c("MYC","EV","PIM","WDR","OBX")    
tmp <- sapply(Rlevels,grepl,Rnames)
apply(tmp,1,function(i)colnames(tmp)[i])
[1] "EV"  "PIM" "WDR" "MYC" "OBX" "EV"  "PIM" "WDR"
```

But I would seriously consider mentioning this to the team of galaxy, as it seems to be rather awkward not to be able to use the symbol for OR...

Comment: Thanks to Joris Meys, This solution works for R in combination with galaxy. For sure, I'm gonna ask the galaxy developers why it doesn't work with character |

Answer (score 2):

I **wouldn't** recommend doing this in general in R as it is far less efficient than the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191429/replacing-rownames-of-data-frame-by-a-sub-string/5191695#5191695) @csgillespie provided, but an alternative is to loop over the various strings you want to match and do the replacements on each string separately, i.e. search for `"MYN"` and replace only in those rownames that match `"MYN"`.

Here is an example using the `x` data from @csgillespie's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191429/replacing-rownames-of-data-frame-by-a-sub-string/5191695#5191695):

```
x <-  c("U2OS.EV.2.7.9", "U2OS.PIM.2.7.9", "U2OS.WDR.2.7.9", "U2OS.MYC.2.7.9",
       "U2OS.OBX.2.7.9", "U2OS.EV.18.6.9", "U2O2.PIM.18.6.9","U2OS.WDR.18.6.9",
       "U2OS.MYC.18.6.9","U2OS.OBX.18.6.9", "X1.U2OS...OBX","X2.U2OS...MYC")
```

Copy the data so we have something to compare with later (this just for the example):

```
x2 <- x
```

Then create a list of strings you want to match on:

```
matches <- c("MYC","EV","PIM","WDR","OBX")
```

Then we loop over the values in `matches` and do three things (numbered `##X` in the code):

1. Create the regular expression by pasting together the current match string `i` with the other bits of the regular expression we want to use,
2. Using `grepl()` we return a logical indicator for those elements of `x2` that contain the string `i`
3. We then use the same style `gsub()` call as you were already shown, but use only the elements of `x2` that matched the string, and replace only those elements.

The loop is:

```
for(i in matches) {
    rgexp <- paste(".*(", i, ").*", sep = "") ## 1
    ind <- grepl(rgexp, x)                    ## 2
    x2[ind] <- gsub(rgexp, "\\1", x2[ind])    ## 3
}
x2
```

Which gives:

```
> x2
 [1] "EV"  "PIM" "WDR" "MYC" "OBX" "EV"  "PIM" "WDR" "MYC" "OBX" "OBX" "MYC"
```